# Constantly scroll text up within a div

Tags: jquery

I need a very simple jQuery to constantly scroll a list of text items up without using a plugin. I know this is probably fairly simple but I can't find an example that I can use and I have already spent too much time on it at work.

No parameters will need to be changed by mouse hover or button click, so everything can be ran within document.ready and never touched again. My only request is that, ideally, it should be constantly looped.

Comment: I found an example here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?727088-Jquery-scroll-some-text-inside-a-div-with-overflowhere that worked fine in the CMS I am using. It used a couple of links at the bottom and the mouse hover event to call functions to animate the text. This seemed to work perfectly but when I tried to transfer to document.ready I could not get it to work again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short:

```
function cycle($item, $cycler){
    setTimeout(cycle, 2000, $item.next(), $cycler);

    $item.slideUp(1000,function(){
        $item.appendTo($cycler).show();        
    });

}

cycle($('#cycler div:first'),  $('#cycler'));
```

With `#cycler` being the container with the `div`s that are to be cycled. [See demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/hGcV2/1/)

Answer (score 2):

wrote a jquery plugin for this just now.

```
$('.scrolling-div').rollup({speed:2000});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmPPe/5/

Answer (score 1):

Basic code that will work, but stops at the bottom:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var $c = $('#container');
        $c.scrollTop($c.scrollTop() + 1)
}, 100);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/55AY2/

I'm not sure what you mean by "constantly looped".

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks.